# JSF setKeepMessages(true) stopped working for Chrome on redirect

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces

I am trying to display a success message in the case of a succesful user creation after it redirects from the create_user page to the users list.

This specific part of code used to work fine for Chrome, Firefox and Edge browsers.

The button which creates the user on the respected xhtml page:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myHandler.createUpdateUser}" value="#{msg.save}" />
```

which calls this specific code :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public Class myClass implements Serializable {

  public void createUpdateUser(){
    myBean.createUpdateUser();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, StringUtils.EMPTY));
    externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
    externalContext.redirect(new StringBuilder(externalContext.getRequestContextPath())
                        .append("/users/list_users.jsf");
  }
}
```

Both pages can display messages as follows :

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
```

Now it works only for Firefox and Edge.
When creating a user in chrome the success message appears  spontaneously on the create_user page and redirects succesfully to the list page without displaying the message. The message is also not in FacesContext.getMessageList();
I tried switching from actionListener to action in the commandButton which
successfully worked for Chrome, but unfortunately did not work correct for the other two.

I am using Primefaces v6.0, java 1.8, jboss eap 7.

Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Comment: Tried setting the keepMessages before adding the message? Tried using plain jsf components?

Comment: I have already tried adding keepMessages before adding the message. Which components do you mean?

Comment: It seems like the code works fine. The issue was javascript related. Js code interfered with jsf lifecycle and delayed the process. Thanx for your time